# Drupal's Boost on Aegir system "Could not create the directory cache/normal/mysite.com"

Tags: permissions, drupal-7, debian

I have a Barracuda install of Nginx and Drupal's Aegir on a Debian 6 (Squeeze) box. I have the boost module enabled but it is not working. I am getting the following error in my logs;

"Could not create the directory cache/normal/mysite.com on your system"

I have tried  chown-ing the owner and group to www-data.www-data and chmod-ing permissions to 777,776 and 775

Nothing seems to work. Anybody know why boost is unable to write to a cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was applying permissions to cache in the wrong folder. /sites/mysite.com/cache
The correct folder was /platforms/drupal-7.22/cache